# Capturing git command output with subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to return all git commit hashes for commits that contain 'As delivered' in their commit message.
Essentially, I want to capture the output of the below git command:

```
git log --all -i --grep 'As Delivered' --format='%H'
```

The above git command runs as I expect it to in the command line, returning one matched hash per output line.
Here's the code I'm trying to use to accomplish my goal:

```
def getHashesMatchingGrep(grepStr="As Delivered"):
    grep_option = '--grep=\'' + grepStr + '\''
    format_option = '--format="' + '%H' + '"'
    cmd = ['git', 'log', '--all', '-i', grep_option, format_option]
    print("Using command: " + str(cmd))
    process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
    #return namedtuple('Std', 'out, err')(process.stdout.read(), process.stderr.read())
    return process.returncode, stdout, stderr

code, out, err = getHashesMatchingGrep()
print('code = {}\nout = {}\nerr = {}'.format(code, out, err))
```

But all I get as output from this is:

```
Using command: ['git', 'log', '--all', '-i', "--grep='As Delivered'", '--format="%H"']
code = 0
out = b''
err = b''
```

I've also tried defining text=True, and shell=True for my Popen call. In this case I get 'None' from err, but still no other output.
If I edit my function so that cmd=['git','log','--all'] I get something, but still, why won't it return anything when I add the --grep line? I know if I type the same git command (with grep) in the cmd terminal I get results.

Am I not understanding how subprocess is supposed to work? It seems to run OK, but if it is failing, why aren't I getting the stderr? I'm very confused, please help!

Comment: I will add that git is installed and in my windows cmd path.

Comment: maybe it finds nothing in repo and you get empty output. Did you test command `git log --all -i --grep 'As Delivered' --format='%H'` directly in console? When I run it in console on some my repo then it gives me empty output.

Comment: This isn't a Git issue: `--subprocess` *without* `--shell` means you don't want to add quotes.

Answer (score 3):

It appears I hadn't 'tokenized' my cmd array appropriately.
Before:

```
grep_option = '--grep=\'' + grepStr + '\''
format_option = '--format="' + '%H' + '"'
cmd = ['git', 'log', '--all', '-i', grep_option, format_option]
```

After:

```
format_option = '--format="' + '%H' + '"'
cmd = ['git', 'log', '--all', '-i', '--grep', grepStr, format_option]
```

Comment: Or just the literal `'--format="%H"'`, since your string constants add up to that. You probably really just wanted `'--format=%H'` though, without the double quotes, just as you didn't really want the double quotes in your `--grep`. Note that `git log` with `--format=%H` is generally best converted to `git rev-list`, though, if at all possible.

Comment: @torek Yeah, I thought about using rev-list but I'm not as familiar with it. That grep is important, will rev-list output allow me to grep on commit messages? I also advanced the way I'm doing this to -p --follow filename, I don't know if rev-list allows for that

Comment: `git rev-list` and `git log` are sister commands, where rev-list is the plumbing variety and log is the porcelain one. Unfortunately, they're not quite *twin* sisters. If you want `--follow` you are forced to use `git log`, which respects user configuration, which is a real problem. Someone is trying to add a `log.graph` setting and it's breaking gitk and others that use `git log` as porcelain, when they would like to use `git log` as plumbing.

Comment: (The `--grep` stuff *is* supported by `git rev-list`, but `--follow` isn't.)

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the extra details, I appreciate it!